# Typescript: Create declarations for UMD module which is written in TS

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-declarations

I wrote a little library in TS for learning purpose. I am using webpack to create a JS UMD module from my typescript.

My project structure looks like this:

```
|-dist
    |-js
        |-my-lib.min.js    // Minified library as UMD module
|-src
    |-ts
        |-types
        |-interfaces
        |-utils
        |-components
            |-button.ts
            |-textField.ts
            |-dropdownMenu.ts
        |-my-lib.ts    // Source file for UMD lib
```

`my-lib.ts` file:

```
import {Button} from './components/button';
import {TextField} from './components/textField';
import {DropdownMenu} from './components/dropdownMenu';

export {
    Button,
    TextField,
    DropdownMenu,
}
```

So when including `my-lib.min.js` via `src` in HTML, I can use my components, for instance: (*The UMD module is named with webpack in `myLib`*).

```
const username = new myLib.TextField();
```

Now I want to use my lib in a new ts project. I do not want that the TS files are delivered but the declarations only. So that I can use my ts lib like it would be a JS UMD module, for instance:

```
const username : myLib.TextField = new myLib.TextField();
```

How can I achieve this?

1. Is it possible to create a declaration file automatically?
2. When no, how can I create a declaration file manually? How is it structured?

I tried `tsc --declaration src\ts\my-lib.ts`. Then a `my-lib.d.ts` file was created but also declaration files for all imported components, so `buttond.d.ts`, `textfield.d.ts` and `dropdownMenu.d.ts`.

Also my declaration file for `my-lib.ts` looks pretty the same than the original file (because its all about import / export and no type or function declarations). So I do not think that this file would help me.

My `.tsconfig` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    },
    "lib": [
        "umd"
    ],
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yeah, I am using the `dts-bundle-generator` now. This package is targeting my `my-lib.ts` file and creates one single `.d.ts` file for all included dependencies. But I have to add the following lines to get it work as I want (as global library which is included as `<script>` tag in my html page): ````export as namespace myLib;

export { };

declare global {
 var myLib: typeof myLib;
}````

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in one of the comments, a possible solution to this issue can be: `dts-bundle-generator`. It takes typescript code and bundles it into a single file, it also adds the umd namespace if used with `--umd-module-name` flag.
https://github.com/timocov/dts-bundle-generator